# Error with POST command

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-6, idhttp

I have a problem with a POST command. I'm using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component on Delphi 6.

I get a token with this POST command:

```
URI:=EdUri.Text+Edit5.Text;   
Http1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
Http1.Request.Accept   := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
Http1.Response.ContentType:='application/json';
Http1.Post(URI, Params, Resp);
```

I then do a GET command with the token:

```
URI:=EdUri.Text;// := 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/';
Http1.Response.ExtraHeaders.Values['Authorization'] :='Bearer '+sTocken;
Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['Authorization'] :='Bearer '+sTocken;
Http1.get(URI+Chaine,  Resp);
```

But I don't know how to do a POST command with the token:

```
Params := TStringStream.Create('code=''FF''&libelle=''test222''');
URI :='http://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Massi/pays/13';
Http1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
Http1.Request.Accept   := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
Http1.Response.ContentType:='application/json';
Http1.Response.ExtraHeaders.Values['Authorization'] :='Bearer '+sTocken;
Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['Authorization'] :='Bearer '+sTocken;
Http1.Post(URI, Params, Resp);
```

I'm getting an error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: This error means that the resource http://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Massi/pays/13 does not accept HTTP POST requests, so make source that you are using the correct request type

Comment: Also, you should not be populating the `TIdHTTP.Response` values at all when sending a request. And, the correct way to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted request is with the overloaded version of `Post()` that takes a `TStrings` as input instead of a `TStream`. And, setting `Request.Accept` to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` is just plain wrong. Set `Request.Accept` to the media type(s) that you are willing to accept from the server (like JSON), not the media type you are sending to the server. Or, don't set the `Request.Accept` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can do a POST, but I can not do a PUT, I added
       Params: = TStringList.Create;
       Params.Add (EdPost.Text);
       Params.Add ( '_ METHOD =PUT');
but I have a message ERROR 405 Method not allowed

Comment: As Remy said, the error has to do with the fact you are doing a ‘post’ http command, which is not accepted by the server. Try using ‘TIdHttp.Put’ instead. And change you question title form using ‘post’ to ‘put’.